# is there a way to open a popup box in the center of the screen when somebody click the close button on browser?

Tags: magento, browser, popup, onbeforeunload

i want to show a % discount box on the center of the browser when somebody clicks the close button of the browser window . I have tried the

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

};

function formSubmit() {
  window.unbeforeunload = null; 
  }
```

function but it opens the browsers own dialogue box, how can i customize it? or better, how can i open my own box? so that i can change the position and style of it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The onbeforeunload event is the only event that fires (besides the onunload event, but don't use this) before the window leaves the page. The onbeforeunload event is special because it is the only event that will automatically be fired off once the user tries to leave the page, but has the option of staying on the page if the user clicks cancel.

So, to directly answer your question, if the user closes the window, hits the back button, or navigates to a new URL, you will have to use the onbeforeunload event. You can add text inside of the pop-up, but some of the default text will always stay there. You just have to return a string.

Now, if the user were to click on a link that is a part of your application or tries to log out, you can anchor an event to that, which could make a window pop up that has the "% discount box". The reason you can't anchor an event to the back button, external URL, or the close window button is that they don't belong to your application. So once they click one of those, the browser goes off on its way with nothing you can do, except for the onbeforeunload event.